# Output file #0 does not contain any stream android

Tags: image, audio, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

```
String cmd[] = {"ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i " + imagePath + " -i " + newAudioPath + " -shortest " + outputVideo};
```

I want to create video from compile one image and one audio,

Here i pass image and audio path from device file location absolute file and last one pass the location needed to create video path.

Am i doing wrong? then guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Share the **full** log. Add -report and share report if you can't capture the log.

Comment: i solve issue by removing ffmpeg  from command